# disable preselected checkbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, registerstartupscript

I have these lines of code which select checkbox based on preselected flag

```
if (objX.PreSelected)
{
    string js = "if(document.getElementById('" + CheckBoxId + "').checked==false) document.getElementById('" + CheckBoxId + "').click();";
    if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(CheckBoxId))
         Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), CheckBoxId, js, true);
}
```

after this is done I need to disable that preselected checkbox.
I tried below but it did not work

```
string js = "if(document.getElementById('" + CheckBoxId + "').checked==false) {document.getElementById('" + CheckBoxId + "').click();document.getElementById('" + CheckBoxId + "').disabled ='disabled';}";
```

UPDATE - I could disable that checkbox but problem is it's not sent back to server.
I am new to asp.net programming, please suggest.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `document.getElementById('" + CheckBoxId + "').disabled ="disabled";` you should use `setAttribute`. `document.getElementById('" + CheckBoxId + "').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to do this with javascript? Otherwise you could do something like:

```
if (objX.PreSelected)
{
    checkBox.Checked = true;
    checkBox.Enabled = false;
}
```

or

```
checkBox.Checked = objX.PreSelected;
checkBox.Enabled = objX.PreSelected == false;
```

To make a CheckBox disabled using JavaScript you can write

```
document.getElementById('id').disabled = 'disabled';
```

or

```
document.getElementById('id').disabled = true;
```

No need to do both .click() and .checked = true;